# nginx download the latest file based on filename pattern

Tags: nginx

I upload my installer files with filename pattern `app-installer X.X.exe` e.g. `app-installer 1.12.exe`. Is it possible for nginx to pick the latest version for download link `http://.../app-installer.exe`?

As a workaround I have to manually create a symlink every time I upload a new version:

`app-installer.exe` -> `app-installer 1.12.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible with vanilla nginx since it cannot do math within it's basic config syntax.
However, it's possible with Lua code in it's config, - you can implement any logic you want; minimal programming skills needed.